# Redirect audio to HDMI with XRandr to watch and hear movies

Tags: sound, hdmi, xrandr

I am doing this to watch movies on the large TV screen playing from my Ubuntu laptop Acer Aspire R7:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto --rotate normal --pos 0x0 --right-of eDP-1
```

This works, but it will not redirect audio at all. I am using mpv/mplayer/vlc.

How to play audio over the HDMI?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu have `pavucontrol`, although you may need to install it using APT. This utility has the output device selection called `Profile` for some reason, on the last tab called `Configuration` which may also be confusing. [image]